# Check if Array exists in OPA

Tags: opa

I am struggling to write a policy that should check an element of an array but the array itself is optional.

```html
{
  "load_balancer":[{
     "target_group_arn":true
     }]
 }
```

```
deny[message] {
 message := "Target ARN is missing"
 lb:= [rule | rule:= input.load_balancer[_] ; rule.target_group_arn ]
 ????
}
```

I am not sure how could I proceed. If I simply say count(lb) > 0 , when array is not defined, it is an empty array. Empty array could also be possible when every load_balancer has target_group_arn.

How should I proceed on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it. Thanks.

```
package play

import future.keywords.in

deny[message] {
    not input.load_balancer

    message := "load balancer list missing from input"
}

deny[message] {
    
    some l in input.load_balancer
    not l.target_group_arn
    
    message := "load balancer list item missing arn"
}
```